# How to generate two variables at the same time?

Tags: specman

I have a struct which has two fields X and Y, I have several keeps on them, and i would like to generate them several times at the same time inside the struct itself.

My need is more complicated but this is the main issue i'm facing.
How can we generate two fields at the same time?

Example:

```
struct example {
   X : int;
   Y : int;

   keep X < Y;
   keep Y < 10;
   keep X+Y > 5;

   do_something(cnt : int) is { 
      for i from 1 to cnt {
         gen X and Y;
         print X, Y;
      };
   };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `gen me` doesn't work, you can just declare a variable of type `example` in `do_something(...)` and generate that:

```
  do_something(cnt : int) is { 
      for i from 1 to cnt {
         var obj : example;
         gen obj;
         X = obj.X;
         Y = obj.Y;
         print X, Y;
      };
   };
```